# FirebaseDatabase.getInstance() getting crashed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-gradle-plugin

I have using firebase database in dialog fragment. It getting crashed when below code was run

`private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();`

I searched all the solution such as **changing gradle dependencies and download google-service.json file**

and etc., But problem not solved yet. I attach the all details of my code please give the correct solution. Thanks

```
public class FireViewFragment extends DialogFragment {

TextView name, email, username;
Button ok;
MyDialogInterface myDialogInterface;
private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

public FireViewFragment(MyDialogInterface myDialogInterface) {
    this.myDialogInterface = myDialogInterface;
    Log.d("Interface", "Constractor");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fire_view, container, false);
    name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dis_name);
    email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dis_email);
    username = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dis_uname);
    ok = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.ok);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myDialogInterface.setMyDialogInterface("hi", false);

        }
    });
    return view;
}}
```

> build.gradle(Module.app)

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

> google-service.json file

```
  "project_info": {
"project_number": "961599319300",
"firebase_url": "https://working-2ab0d.firebaseio.com",
"project_id": "working-2ab0d",
"storage_bucket": "working-2ab0d.appspot.com"  },
```

> Logcat

```
05-01 21:56:30.298 29506-29506/com.example.gowsik.working E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.example.gowsik.working, PID: 29506
                                                                        java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzckb()Z in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.example.gowsik.working-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.example.gowsik.working.firebase.FireViewFragment.<init>(FireViewFragment.java:22)
                                                                            at com.example.gowsik.working.activities.FirebaseActivity$2.onClick(FirebaseActivity.java:49)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: I guess it´s related to the different versions of firebase and maps. Try to use `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0`, the same version like firebase is...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs you gave great solution. I already change all changes in gradle dependencies without this. Yhaaa., it's working thanks-lot

Comment: glad to help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different Versions of Google libraries cannot work together. You need to add the same versions, so change your maps libraries to 9.2.0:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of writing

```
private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
```

write

```
private DatabaseReference firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
```

Hope this will  solve your problem

Comment: I try it now this code shows blow warning message Incompatible types.
Required:
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
Found:
com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase

Comment: private DatabaseReference firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); try this one